# Is there a way to install gnome, kde or any other X interface on an Amazon Linux System?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Linux for our server systems.  I would like to get a desktop session there to make it easier to do certain desktop tasks such as manual testing and configuration of those servers.  Is there a way to do that?

My system is a default AWS Linux 2 system and the version information looks like this:

```
# uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-0-160.us-east-2.compute.internal 4.14.243-185.433.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 9 05:55:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# echo `cat /etc/*release | grep "NAME\|VERSION"`
NAME="Amazon Linux" VERSION="2" VERSION_ID="2" PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2" CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
```

Comment: First, make sure you "sudo" before everything. Second, what does "yum grouplist" report?

Comment: ya.. grouplist has just few elements (amazon AMI distro is limited). I've tried to enable epel (yum --enablerepo=epel groupinstall "X Window System") .. and have a lot of errors.... I'm afraid I'll have to switch to Ubuntu ... Thanks

Comment: Seems that you are using version 1. Just in case, there is a tutorial for Amazon Linux 2 - How do I install a GUI on my Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2? (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/)

Comment: this question age is 7 years. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, You cannot install X on amazon Linux. amazon Linux is meant for Server roles and hence X related packages are not available in the repo of amazon Linux.

You need to explore Ubuntu/RHEL or some other flavour of Linux if you need X. OR you can hack your own way of compiling X on Amazon Linux.

Comment: try this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374358/how-to-install-a-gui-on-amazon-aws-ec2-or-emr-with-the-amazon-ami/46374359#46374359

Comment: This answer is now wrong.  I will add a correct answer if the question gets re-opened.