# How to initiate a GUI (xfce4)?

Tags: lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Earlier, I was trying to install a GUI on my Bitnami LAMP machine in AWS Lightsail.

I installed `xfce4`, then rebooted my machine. Other than making my command line inaccessible for a few minutes, it had no effect, even after running the `tasksel` and `startx` commands.

I tried looking up some articles on this, but everything was on AWS EC2, which is not the same.

Does anyone know how I would initiate the GUI?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here! Apart from installing the desktop environment, you also need to install VNC to access the desktop remotely. You can find great tutorials online (for example [this guide](https://developpaper.com/aws-lightsail-ec2-ubuntu-installation-desktop/) or [this YouTube vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emIpPhy-JOM) might help). Please take into account that this is not related to Bitnami, but those tutorials should work. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at those!

Comment: @JotaMartos I'm having a few issues. I followed the instructions from the first article you sent and I followed the instructions to install xfce4. I installed the vnc4server and the xfce4 on my server then I downloaded VNC Viewer on my Mac and edited the configuration files. When I type `[MY_SERVER_IP]:1` into the VNC Viewer address bar, it takes a long time to load and then says that it could not connect to the server. Any idea on what went wrong?

Comment: Hi Leo, can you use `[MY_SERVER_IP]:5901` when connecting to the server? Please ensure port 5901 is open in the firewall before trying to connect.

Comment: @JotaMartos I tried `[MY_SERVER_IP]:5901` several times, but I still get this error after a few minutes of trying to connect: `Timed out waiting for a response from the computer`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous message, you need to open 5901 in the firewall. Did you do so?

Comment: Oops, let me try to do that.

Comment: Ok, so I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374358/how-to-install-a-gui-on-amazon-aws-ec2-or-emr-with-the-amazon-ami/46374359#46374359 to help me with this. Basically, I typed `ssh -i /path/to/key/file.pem -L 5901:localhost:5901 -N bitnami@MY_IP` into my command line on my personal computer and then I typed `localhost:5901` into the address bar. Thanks for your help!